# Como adicionar caracteres em uma string de acordo com uma condição predefinida?

Tags: python

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, após receber uma string (pode ser de números ou letras), retornar essa string com adição de um caractere SE dentro dessa string houverem caracteres repetidos em SEQUÊNCIA.

Usando Python eu sei que existem módulos como o counter que retorna a quantidade de vezes que um caractere é repetido em uma string, porém necessito descobrir se esse caractere é repetido N vezes seguidas.

Pensei em resolver meu problema percorrendo o input do usuário, transformando-o em uma lista, e adicionando o caractere após a sequência, mas não sei se é o jeito mais pythônico de se fazer.

Exemplo:

Se o usuário fornece como entrada "abaabaaaabab".

Após a letra "a" se repetir 4 vezes seguidas,adicionar a letra "c" após isso.

O output seria:

"abaabaaaacbab"

Comment: E se a letra "a" for repetida, digamos 8 vezes seguidas, a saída deve ser "aaaacaaaac" ou apenas "aaaacaaaac"? No primeiro caso eu provavelmente resolveria o problema com substituição simples (substituiria "aaaa" por "aaaac" até que não existam mais sequências "aaaa" na string). Já no segundo caso eu percorreria a String caractere a caractere adicionando os caracteres "a" em uma String ou lista temporária. Sempre que você tiver um caractere que não é "a", verifique se o contador é maior que 4, em caso positivo concatene um "c". Em ambos os casos zere o contador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa Jhonathan, beleza!

Cara de acordo com sua pergunta, voê quer percorrer uma string e achar um seguimento de 4 caracteres iguais e adicionar a letra c após o 4 caractere. Bom quando começei a estudar python fiz algo parecido, então peguei aquele código e adaptei veja se funciona para você.

```py
entrada = input('Digite a sequencia ')
lista = []
contador = 0
for i in range(len(entrada)):

    if i+1 < len(entrada):
        if entrada[i] == entrada[i+1] or entrada[i] == entrada[i-1]:

            if contador == 3:
                lista.append(entrada[i])
                lista.append('c')
                contador = 0
                continue

            contador += 1
        else:
            contador = 0     

        lista.append(entrada[i])    
    else:
        if entrada[i] == entrada[i-1] and contador == 3:
            lista.append(entrada[i])
            lista.append('c')
        else:
            lista.append(entrada[i])

output = ''.join(lista)
```

É um código bem simples, de uma olhada e veja a lógica aplicada e tente fazer alterações a partir deste começo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu implementei o "segundo caso", sugerido no comentário do Anthony Accioly.
Favor testar, abraço!

```
entrada = "abaabaaaabab"

cont = 0
ant = ""
saida = ""

for c in entrada:    

    saida += c    

    if c == ant:
        cont += 1

    if cont == 4:
        saida += "c"
        cont = 0        

    ant = c

print(saida)
```